# How do I change the mouse acceleration curve?

Tags: mouse

How do I tweak the *precise mathematical **curve*** used for the mouse acceleration in Ubuntu?

Comment: This is geeky :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the answer...

Something like this should do the trick:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" \
    "Synaptics Edge Motion Speed" 2000, 5000
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" \
    "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
synclient MinSpeed=1.00 MaxSpeed=3.00 AccelFactor=0.025
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what mouse profile you're using.

[This blog](http://blog.dhampir.no/content/improve-the-mouse-response-and-acceleration-in-debian) describes a new mouse acceleration method added to Debian Squeeze (should also be in Maverick since Squeeze used xorg-server [1.7.7](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=debian) and Maverick used [1.9.0](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu)). You can read the [developer documentation here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=17772).

If you look at the source, you can derive the curve based on which Profile you're using. In the [patch for AccelerationProfile](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=17773), you can see the function `SetAccelerationProfile` which selects your profile. If you look at each of those profiles, you can see how the function is defined.

So to tweak it, you modify whatever inputs your selected profile takes. Presumably these are set in xorg.conf (which, fyi, [doesn't exist by default](https://superuser.com/questions/141802/where-is-xorg-conf-in-ubuntu-10-04)).

To really customize it, you can write your own function and compile your own xorg-server : D

Comment: Aww I'm not nerdy enough to start recompiling pieces of the OS. D: +1 Thanks though... I'll probably accept this if there's no simpler solution. :)

Comment: Minor tweaking should only require changes to the xorg config file, but to figure out the actual curve you'll need to figure out the code. Unless someone else already wanted the same thing.

Comment: I'd imagine I'm not the first person to want to do this, but I haven't found the settings anywhere... :\

Comment: For twiddling with the values, this is probably a more friendly guide: http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration#Configuration  Keep in mind that you probably need to create the xorg.conf file.